# Do all subspaces have a set which generates it?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that if $S$ is a subset of a vector space $V$, then $Span$($S$) is a subspace.

But do all subspaces $W$ necessarily have a set $S$ such that $W$ = Span($S$)?

Comment: Of course, we can take $S = W$.  But perhaps this isn't the answer you're looking for.  Perhaps you're asking if every subspace has a basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any subspace $W$ of $V$ has a basis  in $ V$. A simple consequence of Zorn's Lemma is that every vector space has a basis. Now since $W$ is a vector space itself , it has a basis, say $S$ is the spanning set of $W$. Now since $W$ is s subspace of $V$ ans $S$ is a subset of $W$, by transitivity   $S\subset W\subset V$  such that Span$ (S)=W$.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot